# NSPredicate using Core Data objectID not working inconsistently?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

Wonder if anyone can see the obvious thing I seem to be missing here. I'm working on an app that uses a variety of Core Data entities. These entities store references to a variety of other source files. I want the availability/visibility of the Core Data objects to mirror the availability of the source files.

So at launch, I iterate through the sources and if available I add the NSManagedObjectID of any associated CD objects to an NSMutableSet, lets call it availableObjectIDs.

My understanding is that the using the predicate

```
"self IN..."
```

for Core Data should evaluate based on objects IDs, so in my fetch query I use the NSPredicate

```
"self IN %@", availableObjectIDs
```

This doesn't seem to be working properly. When I fetch objects with entity X, it returns objects whose objectID has *not* been added to availableObjectIDs. I can evaluate the results using

```
[availableObjectIDs contains:object.objectID]
```

and some will return false, even though the predicate should be filtering them out!

Stranger still, the identical predicate *does* appear to work when fetching entity Y. I cannot see any difference in the entity configurations to explain this. I've tried using an NSComparisonPredicate instead, and it seems to be behaving the same way.

Baffled by this seemingly simple issue. Anyone run into something similar?

Comment: A couple of thoughts: a) are the objectIDs temporary ones, where permanent IDs have subsequently been issued, and b) are you on the main thread (or using performBlock)?

Comment: Good questions! Yes, I am sure to obtainPermanentIDs before storing. The fetch is on the main thread. The process to collect the IDs runs in a performBlock (as new objects may be created in that process).

Comment: Does enabling SQLDebug give any clues as to how that predicate is parsed into SQL?

Comment: I'll give that a try!